# Area 51 login issue

Tags: bug, area-51, login

I can login to Area 51 using my Google account, and everything seems fine at first. Until I try to participate, such as answering a question, voting, or creating a new question. At this point the login bar shows me as not logged in, and I am asked to create an account or login again. But when I do I get the crashed flying saucer error. Login works fine on other StackExchange communities. I tried different browsers, clearing cache, clearing cookies, loging out from Google itself, creating another account - no avail. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Just posting about the bug here created a workaround: if you log in to Meta first, then it works! Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other people have seen similar login issues with Area 51. The workaround is to log into [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com) first, as I just did to post my question.

After that everything works as intended.